# Insert Javascript Variable into JSON Object

Tags: javascript, html, variables, frontend

I have a JSON object like this:

```
var values = {
"email": " ' + fn + ' ", // This field is required to identify existing customers.
"first_name": "email",
"last_name": "email",
"address": "email",
"city": "email",
"state": "email",
"zip": "email",
"dob": "email" // This field must match the following format: YYYYMMDD. This field is also required
};
```

I am trying to insert:

```
var fn = 'Tom';
```

But the variable is not appearing. How can i go about this?

Comment: Trying how? Not "appearing" where? (And that's a *JavaScript* object, not a "JSON" object.) *edit* oh well I see now. Yea that won't work.

Comment: use "email": fn , simple as that

Comment: Quiz question: What do a **unicorn** and a **JSON object** have in common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of using JSON with javascript is to create an object in your application, in this case it may look something like this

```
var values = {
   email: "Tom@whatever",
   name: "Tom"
}
```

You can interact with this object however you like, such as

```
values.city = "New York";
```

Then when you are ready to create a JSON object that represents that object, you can use `JSON.stringify()` MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

In this case

```
let jsonString = JSON.stringify(values);
console.log(jsonString);
```

yields this result:

```
{"email":"Tom@whatever","name":"Tom","city":"New York"}
```

This means you don't have to worry about creating a JSON string manually at all!

More info on JSON [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `" ' + fn + ' "` is treated as a string so `fn` will never be replaced. What you're after is:

```
var fn = "Tom";

var values = {
"email": " " + fn + " ", // This field is required to identify existing customers.
"first_name": "email",
"last_name": "email",
"address": "email",
"city": "email",
"state": "email",
"zip": "email",
"dob": "email" // This field must match the following format: YYYYMMDD. This field is also required
};
```

You can just use `email: fn` if you dont need the space in the front and back